# Redux thunk function not being executed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-thunk

I recently started looking at redux thunks. It is my understanding it should be used for dealing with async actions or where there's a need to dispatch actions from within other actions. So I've got my store configured such as:

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./rootReducer";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'; // used by redux-devtools to visualize redux in browser

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    // other store enhancers if any
));

export default store;
```

My reducer looks like:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    user: null,
}

export const authReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case actionTypes.REGISTER_NEW_USER:
            const newUser = action.payload
            return {
                ...state,
                'user': newUser
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

my thunk is the following (notice I commented out the part that makes an async call for simplicity while I just test the functionality of my thunk):

```
// Thunks
export const registerUser = (userData) => {
    console.log("HERE")
    return async (dispatch) => {
        let user = new User();
        try {
            let newUserData;
            console.log(userData)
            // newUserData = await user.register(userData);
            newUserData = {
                'email': 'asdas@gmail.com',
                'token': '234jk23hjkhaSDASD',
            }
            console.log("here in thunk")
            console.log(newUserData)
            cookie.set("user", newUserData.email);
            cookie.set("token", newUserData.token);
            // dispatch(createNewUser(newUserData));
            dispatch({
                type: actionTypes.REGISTER_NEW_USER,
                payload: newUserData
            })
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

    }
}
```

and my component:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onSubmit = data => {
        dispatch(registerUser(data));

    }
```

I've written some tests for these but when executing them, they don't seem to be running the thunk function. The `console.log("HERE")` statement in `registerUser` is executed but none of the logs from within the return method are. What am I missing?

Side question and not as important as the previous one: Now that i'm using Thunks, do all my actions need to be a thunk? or is it ok to have a combination of thunks and actions that are always plain js objects where no async processing is required?

Thanks

Comment: Just a side comment. Haven't used redux and thunk ever since the react hooks and newer state management libraries like zustand appeared. So much easier.

Comment: General FYI: you are writing a very old style of Redux here. Modern Redux is about a fourth of the code, does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES, createStore or connect. I would highly recommend you to look into the official Redux tutorial at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts and get up to speed with modern Redux first. That tutorial will also go through things like thunks.

Comment: @SILENT omg, I just replaced redux by Zustand. It's so much straight forward, I love it so far. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const actionTypes = { REGISTER_NEW_USER: 'REGISTER_NEW_USER' };
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: null,
};

export const authReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.REGISTER_NEW_USER:
      const newUser = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        user: newUser,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ auth: authReducer });
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

const registerUser = () => {
  console.log('HERE');
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      console.log('here in thunk');
      const newUserData = { email: 'asdas@gmail.com', token: '234jk23hjkhaSDASD' };
      dispatch({ type: actionTypes.REGISTER_NEW_USER, payload: newUserData });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
};

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('state:', store.getState());
});
store.dispatch(registerUser());
```

Execution result:

```sh
HERE
here in thunk
state: {
  auth: { user: { email: 'asdas@gmail.com', token: '234jk23hjkhaSDASD' } }
}
```

The doc [Writing Logic with Thunks](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks) is clear:

> For Redux specifically, "thunks" are a pattern of writing functions with logic inside that can interact with a Redux store's dispatch and getState methods.

> Thunks are the standard approach for writing async logic in Redux apps, and are commonly used for data fetching. However, they can be used for a variety of tasks, and can contain both synchronous and asynchronous logic.

You are right, it's ok to have a combination of thunks and actions that are always plain js objects. The plain js object actions are often used for UI actions.

But a better way is to use [action creators](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-7-standard-patterns#action-creators) to create a [Flux Standard Actions](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-7-standard-patterns#flux-standard-actions)